# Estimate size of SAS Dataset for Macro Variable

Tags: sas

I am trying to get the size of SAS dataset to put into the macro variable. Though not able to get good hints for it. Options which I am considering are given below:

```
proc sql;
    select *
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = "REPOS"

;
quit;

proc contents data = repos.ajk;
run;
```

Comment: Do you mean file size, number of records, or something else?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I am looking for size in terms of GB or MB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
proc sql noprint;
select put(filesize/1024/1024, 16.2 -L) into :sizeMB from dictionary.tables
where libname = 'MYLIB'
and memname = 'MYTABLE'
;
quit;

%put &sizeMB;
```

Comment: Wonderful my friend. How about GB ?

Comment: I got it. Just add one more 1024 .